# sorting data in specific order

Tags: java, collections, set

Here my rowId's are like the below

1

1.1

1.2

.

1.9

2

2.1

.

.
3
.
.
9

.

9.9

10

10.1

```
List<MyBean> sortedList = rootItems.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getRowId)) .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By using the above code I am getting the output like below.

> 1
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> 12
>
> 2
>
> 2.1
>
> 2.2
>
> .
>
> .

but I want output like the below

> 1
>
> 1.1
>
> 1.1.1
>
> 1.1.1.1
>
> 1.2
>
> 1.3
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 1.9
>
> 10
>
> 11
>
> .
>
> 2
>
> 2.1
>
> 2.2
>
> 2.3
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 3
>
> 3.1
>
> 3.2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 4
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 9
>
> 9.1
>
> 9.2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 9.9
>
> 10
>
> 10.1
>
> .
>
> .

like this it need to proceed

If I want like this which Set I need to use

Comment: your question contain unnecessary lines can you remove them please

Comment: What is the return type of `getRowId`? Looks like it's a `String` to me?

Comment: Parse to numeric(double ex.) in the sort/comapre part.

Comment: Parse your strings to sequences of numbers, then compare those. Strings are compared character by character and thus `1.1` is greater than `10` because `.` is greater than `0`. Alternatively change your ids so that all elements have equal length, e.g. by prepending zeros. Thus `1.1` could become `01.01` (or even more zeros) etc.

Comment: @daniu yes, the returntype of rowId is String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing these strings would be a lot easier if you normalized them internally, to a format that can then be sorted. I'd suggest to pad the individual items with zeroes, something like this:

```
private static final Pattern SINGLE_DIGIT = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d)\\b");
...
String padWithZeroes = SINGLE_DIGIT.matcher(yourInputString).replaceAll("0$1");
```

now just sort on the padded strings.
This is assuming that the highest number will be 2 digits, if not, we will need to adjust the regex and the logic will be slightly more complicated.

---

If any of the numeric segments can be longer than 2 digits, then it will get more complicated. Here's a method that pads all segments to the maximum length:

```
static String padWithZeroes(String yourInputString, int digits) {
    final Matcher matcher = SINGLE_DIGIT.matcher(yourInputString);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(matcher.find()){

        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, pad(digits - matcher.group().length())+matcher.group());
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

static String pad(int length) {
    final char[] chars = new char[length];
    Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
    return new String(chars);
}
```

The problem here is that you will have to know the value of the `digits` parameter up front, so either you know your data, or you will have to do a separate iteration in which you measure the max length.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it on my computer, but it seems like the data are not translated to double for the comparison. I think adding `mapToDouble(i->i.getRowId)` before the sorted would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, the OP listed only 2 levels but I'm pretty sure he'll eventually have 3 or more levels, i.e. `1.1.1` - parsing to double would fail pretty fast.

Comment: Well from the question it is not clearly defined what the input or output data are, if he indeed plans to do that, he must implement his own comparator as other people suggested.

Comment: @NareshDonthula As I said to my previous comment then you need to implement your own comparator. In high level how I would go about it, would be to split the strings for dots, convert them to integers iterate and compare through the generated Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use a own `compare()` method like this:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String id1, String id2) {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(id1);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(id2);
        return Double.compare(d1, d2);
    }
});
```

OR just parse/mapTo the ID into double and compare/sort it then.

Comment: Well, the OP listed only 2 levels but I'm pretty sure he'll eventually have 3 or more levels, i.e. `1.1.1` - parsing to double would fail pretty fast.

Comment: Then he can replace all `'.'` with `''` and parse the full number to `int`/`double` and add '0' to 6letters , so `1.1.99` < `2.0` because `119900` < `200000`   - it´s easily to make it up to X letters and levels

Comment: Hmm, `1.1.99` already _is_ smaller than `2.0`. Consider `2.1.1` vs. `10.1.1`: your approach would result in `211000` and `101100` - doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comment the problem is that strings are compared on a character-by-character basis. Thus you'll need to either alter the strings so that each element has equal length and each character position corresponds to the same position in the other ids or parse the elements into sequences of numbers

Alternative 1 has the drawback that you'd need to have a fixed maximum length for each component (i.e. for a, b, c in `a.b.c` etc.) or you'd have to calculate the number of elements first.

Alternative 2 thus seems to be better, but parsing the strings each time you compare them might be a little costly. Hence you might want to introduce a class that represents your id and which holds the actual id string as well as a parsed version. That class could implement `Comparable` and operate on the parsed version only.

Example:

```
class MyRowId implements Comparable<MyRowId> {
  private final String id;

  //when serializing instances of that class you might want to ignore this array 
  //and upon deserialization parse the string again
  private final int[] parsed;

  public MyRowId( String idString ) {
    id = idString;
    parsed = Arrays.stream( idString.split("\\.") ).mapToInt( Integer::parseInt ).toArray();
  }

  public int compareTo( MyRowId other )  {
    //Compare the elements one by one until we run out of elements or hit a difference
    //There might be a more Java8-ish way but I didn't find it yet
    for( int i = 0; i < Math.min( parsed.length, other.parsed.length ); i++ ) {
      int r = Integer.compare( parsed[i], other.parsed[i] );
      if( r != 0 ) {
        return r;
      }
    }

    //If we're here all compared elements were equal but one id might be longer so compare the lengths.
    //That would handle things like comparing "1.1" to "1.1.1" where the latter is greater.
    return Integer.compare( parsed.length, other.parsed.length );
  }
}
```

Comment: in my question the rootItems is Set<MyBean> rootItems = new HashSet<>();

Comment: @NareshDonthula sorry, I'm at work so I don't have that much time.

Comment: @NareshDonthula just use it as you'd use the string you're currently using. Assuming `MyBean` has a field `rowId` make the type of that field `MyRowId` instead of string.

Comment: if I change that `rowId` in MyBean it is effecting to saving functionality

Comment: The type MyRowId from the descriptor computed for the target context is not visible here.

Comment: I have updated the question with more data please check once

Comment: @NareshDonthula I can't dive too much into your code and that's out of scope for SO anyways. If you aren't experienced enough there are still a couple options: 1) ask a more experienced collegue to help you out, 2) try it yourself and if read tutorials if needed, 3) don't use `MyRowId` but provide a comparator that parses the ids and compares the int arrays each time (you can easily adapt the code I posted) - that solution doesn't yield the best performance but should get the job done without having to change much of your existing code base.

Answer (score -2):

If you had specified the return type of getRowId() then the implementation might be different.

---

What you may have to do is to define a Comparator for the class MyBean. It can be implemented as

- class
- anonymous class
- lambda expression.

In your case it could be:

```
class MyBeanComparator implements Comparator<MyBean>{
  public static final MyBeanComparator INSTANCE = new MyBeanComparator();
  public int compare(MyBean b1, MyBean b2){
         //your custom rules
      }
}
```

Then

```
List<MyBean> sortedList = rootItems.stream().sorted(MyBeanComparator.INSTANCE::compare) .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Well his issue is that he would implement `compare(MyBean b1, MyBean b2)` as `b1.getId().compareTo(b2)`, so this doesn't answer the question at all.